# Remove everything but browser from Porteus 32 bit

Tags: linux, kiosk

I have a task of creating kiosk 32 bit system. However Porteus kiosk 32 bit was abandoned by developers and include only old version of Firefox. Is it possible then to cut everything, but Firefox from regular (not kiosk) Porteus?

Comment: What did you try exactly?

Comment: There is very little documentation on porteus and I didn't try anything, because I simply do not know how to do it. Porteus work 100% from memory so changing anything will not survive reboot. We need to modify modules, not online system. So I think xfce module should be removed - but how do I configure xorg module to launch browser? Or may be I need to modify xfce module so that it will not load anything but browser. Unfortunately porteus official forum are of zero help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same situation currently using porteus 3.2 and 2.0
My issue is with 2.0
I found a newbie way to do it

It seems cause this system is slack based. most of the modules belong to that form

So in my 2.0 version there is an app called "porteus package manager" for slackware ther is a button "remove package". Then several modules installed apears

I started removing what i though was innofensive. I have no idea about linux bt ait seems it worked

Hope it works